# Elements shouldn`t duplicate

Tags: java, android, arrays, duplicates

I have programmed a quiz, there I created an array of the questions,  choices and the answer. The Arrays are in the QuestionLibrary. In my main activity (Quiz Activity) I randomize the questions, after every correct answer the questions appear in random rows. It works fine, I only don`t want that the questions do not repeat them self like: "What is my name", "how are you" "What is my name". They should only appear **ONCE**. For Example, there are 13 questions, I want that every question will be only asked only once but in random orders and not several times. How can I set that up? (I am beginner)

Quiz Activiy:

```
    package amapps.impossiblequiz;

       import android.content.Intent;
       import android.os.Bundle;
       import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
       import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
       import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
       import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
       import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
       import android.view.MenuItem;
       import android.view.View;
       import android.widget.Button;
       import android.widget.TextView;
       import android.widget.Toast;

       public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
private Toolbar mToolbar;
private MenuItem menuItem;
private Intent in;

private QuestionLibrary mQuestionLibrary = new QuestionLibrary();

private TextView mScoreView;
private TextView mQuestionView;
private Button mButtonChoice1;
private Button mButtonChoice2;
private Button mButtonChoice3;

private String mAnswer;
private int mScore = 0;
private int mQuestionNumber = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

    //Randromize the row of the questions
    QuestionLibrary q = new QuestionLibrary();
    System.out.printf("Question:0 Choice:(%s, %s, %s) Answer:%s%n",
            q.getChoice1(0), q.getChoice2(0), q.getChoice3(0), q.getCorrectAnswer(0));
    q.shuffle();
    System.out.printf("Question:0 Choice:(%s, %s, %s) Answer:%s%n",
            q.getChoice1(0), q.getChoice2(0), q.getChoice3(0), q.getCorrectAnswer(0));

    //End randomizer

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.nav_action);

    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);

    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);
    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); //Able to see the Navigation Burger "Button"


    NavigationView mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nv1);
    mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem){
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                case(R.id.nav_stats):
                    Intent accountActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Menu2.class);
                    startActivity(accountActivity);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });



        mScoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score_score);
        mQuestionView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
        mButtonChoice1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice1);
        mButtonChoice2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice2);
        mButtonChoice3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice3);


        updateQuestion();

        //Start of Button Listener1
        mButtonChoice1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //My logic for Button goes in here

                if (mButtonChoice1.getText() == mAnswer) {
                    mScore = mScore + 1;
                    updateScore(mScore);
                    updateQuestion();
                    mQuestionLibrary.shuffle();


                    //This line of code is optional...
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Wrong... Try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, Menu2.class);
                    intent.putExtra("score",mScore); //pass score to Menu2
                    startActivity(intent);




                }
            }


        });
        //End of Button Listener1

        //Start of Button Listener2
        mButtonChoice2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //My logic for Button goes in here

                if (mButtonChoice2.getText() == mAnswer) {
                    mScore = mScore + 1;
                    updateScore(mScore);
                    updateQuestion();
                    mQuestionLibrary.shuffle();



                    //This line of code is optional...
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Oh... wrong your score is 0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, Menu2.class);
                    intent.putExtra("score",mScore); //pass score to Menu2
                    startActivity(intent);




                }
            }


        });
        //End of Button Listener2

        //Start of Button Listener3
        mButtonChoice3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //My logic for Button goes in here

                if (mButtonChoice3.getText() == mAnswer) {
                    mScore = mScore + 1;
                    updateScore(mScore);
                    updateQuestion();
                    mQuestionLibrary.shuffle();



                    //This line of code is optional...
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Come on, that was not so hard...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, Menu2.class);
                    intent.putExtra("score",mScore); //pass score to Menu2
                    startActivity(intent);




                }
            }


        });
        //End of Button Listener3

    }


private void updateQuestion() {

    if (mQuestionNumber < mQuestionLibrary.getLength()) {
        mQuestionView.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getQuestion(mQuestionNumber));
        mButtonChoice1.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice1(mQuestionNumber));
        mButtonChoice2.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice2(mQuestionNumber));
        mButtonChoice3.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice3(mQuestionNumber));

        mAnswer = mQuestionLibrary.getCorrectAnswer(mQuestionNumber);
        mQuestionNumber++;
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Last Question! You are very intelligent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, Menu2.class);
        intent.putExtra("score",mScore); //pass score to Menu2
        startActivity(intent);


    }

}

    private void updateScore ( int point){
        mScoreView.setText("" + mScore);

    }


    @Override //Makes that the "Burger" Item, shows the Drawer if someone clicks on the simbol
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){
        if (mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

Question Library:

```
    package amapps.impossiblequiz;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.List;

    public class QuestionLibrary {

private final String[] [] mChoices ={
        {"1993", "1986", "1967"},
        {"-260", "-272,15", "279,15"},
        {"a plant","The active substance of marijuana" , "a spider"},
        {"6", "10","8"},
        {"12","15","10"},
        {"Uranus","Neptune","Saturn"},
        {"HCl","NaCl","CO"},
        {"John F. Kennedy", "Richard Nixon","James A. Garfield"},
        {"Canada","Denmark", "Greenland is an own state?"},
        {"12","20","14"},
        {"10","12","14"},
        {"not","never","now"},
        {"Leningrad","Wolgograd","Dimitrijgrad"}

};
private final String mQuestions[] = {
        "When was the European Union founded?",
        "How many Grad Celsius is one Kelvin?",
        "What is THC?",
        "How many legs has a spider?",
        "How many stars has the European flag?",
        "Which is the seventh planet from the sun?",
        "What is the chemical formula of salt?",
        "Who said: Ich bin ein berliner?",
        "To which country belongs Greenland?",
        "What is the result of: 2 + 2 *5?",
        "How many mountains are higher than 8000 meter/26.246 ft?",
        "A famous quote is: to be, or____ to be!",
        "What is the name of Stalingrad nowadays?"

};



private final String mCorrectAnswers[] = {
        "1993", "-272,15", "The active substance of marijuana",
        "8", "12","Uranus","NaCl","John F. Kennedy",
        "Denmark","12","14","not","Wolgograd"

};

private final List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<>();

public QuestionLibrary() {
    for (int i = 0; i < mQuestions.length; ++i)
        indexes.add(i);
}

private int index(int i) {
    return indexes.get(i);
}

public String getQuestion(int a) {
    return mQuestions[index(a)];
}

public String getChoice1(int a) {
    return mChoices[index(a)][0];
}

public String getChoice2(int a) {
    return mChoices[index(a)][1];
}

public String getChoice3(int a) {
    return mChoices[index(a)][2];
}

public String getCorrectAnswer(int a) {
    return mCorrectAnswers[index(a)];
}

public int getLength() {
    return mQuestions.length;
}

public void shuffle() {
    Collections.shuffle(indexes);
}
}
```

Comment: In your Question library, maintain a list or index of already asked questions in an array and just check if that is being repeated, then get another one.

Comment: Just remove all the `mQuestionLibrary.shuffle();` calls? You are already shuffling once at the beginning: `q.shuffle();`.  That gives your random order. You don't then need to shuffle *again* after every answer.

Comment: @kapsym you probably meant a set of indices not a list

Comment: Hello well thats problably the best way... how can I set up  that it shuffles only one time? on beginning of the new Activity?

Comment: @efekctive yep a set or even a array can be used if used correctly. Matter of preference

Comment: @ProjectX As I mentioned have an array or a Set called AlreadyAskedQuestions and before populating the next question, just check if the question is already there in your AlreadyAskedQuestions Collection, If its there don't ask that question and move to next one. Also as Mr Spoon mentioned that you need to do q.shuffle just once to start with a random set of questions. You will still need the AlreadyAskedQuestions because if your activity closes in between then your questions will start again.

Comment: I already solved it but thanks for your help! I solved it like your technique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shuffle the collection once when you load the activity, rather than after every time a question is answered.

Comment: Remove all the `mQuestionLibrary.shuffle();` from the button onClick listeners. Looks like you already have one in the onCreate so leave that one and it should work

Comment: Now the row of the questions is every tme the same

Comment: I solved it... i only pasted mQuestionLibrary.shuffle(); at the beginning andnow it works fine thanks bro! :D